# What url(s) are set for mavenCentral()?

Tags: maven, gradle

What urls are set behind mavenCentral() in a build.gradle file?

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The used URL is https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ as you can see at https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/7e97aa23a54b4fea1005ab9f02ee2483246e320c/subprojects/core-api/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ArtifactRepositoryContainer.java#L52